# Setting a custom statsd stat_name_handler in Airflow 2 (GCP Composer)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, statsd

I'm trying to set a custom statsd [`stat_name_handler`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#stat-name-handler) for Airflow 2.6.3 (part of GCP Composer 2) to prevent the DAGs from failing with `airflow.exceptions.InvalidStatsNameException` - e.g. due to the `stat_name` exceeding a length of 250 characters.

I haven't found much documentation about this topic, but from the [Airflow source](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/8fb4c71857324fa2366179819830d53f32ef5a3f/tests/core/test_stats.py#L507) it seems the function need to be referenced with a dotted path.

**What I tried**

I tried to follow the [Airflow module management guide](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/modules_management.html) and to create the folder structure under the `plugins` folder - which should be added to the PYTHONPATH by Airflow - with the following configuration:

**Folder structure:**

```
plugins/
└── my_company/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── custom_handlers.py
```

**custom_handlers.py**

```py
def shorten_stat_name_handler(stat_name: str) -> str:
    # my logic
    return stat_name
```

configuration value: `my_company.custom_handlers.shorten_stat_name_handler`

**Outcome**

`airflow-triggerer No module named 'my_company'`

What is the correct way to pass a custom stat_name_handler?

Comment: It seems that although `airflow-triggerer` complains about the module not found, the statsd handler is loaded and recognized since `InvalidStatsNameException` is not thrown anymore and overall Composer seems healthy.